# Get a Decimal from a String

Tags: swift, string, integer, decimal

I have a problem to get a Decimal here.
I have tried this code but the results is 9.0 , How can i get 0.9 ?

```
let distances = "0.9 mil"    
let stratr = distances.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
for item in stratr {
    let components = item.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
    let part = components.joined(separator: "")
                    
    if let doubVal = Double(part) {
        print("this is a number -> \(doubVal)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the string by the space character and then initialize a Float using the first component.

```
let str = "0.9 mil"
let decimal = str.components(separatedBy: " ").first.flatMap { Float($0) }

print(decimal) // 0.9
```

Comment: That's very easy to use, and better than mine @Callam

Comment: In different regions(different OS settings) decimal symbol may be "." or ",". So correct solution must work with all of regions :) This does not

Answer (score 1):

The `String` struct provides an instance method that can be used to remove characters based on a given `CharacterSet`. In this case, you can use the `letters` and `whitespaces` character sets to isolate your decimal value and then create a `Decimal` from it.

```
let distances = "0.9 mil"

let decimal = Decimal(string: distances.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.letters.union(.whitespaces)))

if let decimal = decimal {
    print(decimal) // Prints 0.9
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {
    /// "0.9 mil" => "0.9"
    var decimals: String {
        return trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
    }

    /// "0.9" => 0.9
    var doubleValue: Double {
        return Double(self) ?? 0
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let distance = "0.9 mil"
print(distance.decimals) // "0.9"
print(distance.decimals.doubleValue) // 0.9
print(distance.doubleValue) // 0 (because Double("0.9 mil") => nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i find the Answer

```
let distances = "0.9 mil"    
let stratr = distances.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
            for item in stratr {
                let components = item.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
                let part = components.joined(separator: ".")

                if let doubVal = Double(part) {
                    print("this is a number -> \(doubVal)")
                }
```

I think when i set Joined(separator : ".") it will joined the String with an "." as separator